# Google Apps Script Email Notification Not Functioning Correctly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I could really use some help, and I'd really appreciate any pointers anyone can give.  I know there are some other **similar** questions out there, but from what I can find, no one else has this **specific** issue/request.

I have a Google Sheet that three different people collaborate on.  I have this notification script that will notify specific users via email about **any** changes to any of the cells in the F column.  Importantly, this email notification also contains the value of the A cell in that row that has had it's F cell value changed.

However, what I'm really trying to achieve is a notification script that will email a specified person **only** when any cell in column F has a new value of "Yes" in Sheet2 of the master sheet.

The code I have so far is (that sends a notification when any change happens in the F column):

```
function sendNotification(e) {
  var received = e.value; //Gets the value of the edited cell
};
    function sendNotification() {
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 2");
          var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
          var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
          var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
          var received = ss.getRange('F2:F').getValue();
          var recipients = "example@gmail.com";
          var message = '';
          if(received==="Yes"){ 
            message = sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
            var subject = 'A cell value '+ sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + ' has been received';
            var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: «' + row + '». New comment: «' + cellvalue + '». For message: «' + message + '»';
           MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body)};
        Logger.log('received value: ' + received);
        };
```

Comment: Use a `Logger.log('received value: ' + received);` statement to check the value of the `received` variable.  Run the code, then in the VIEW menu, choose LOGS.

Comment: I just added that and checked the log and saw this:

`[15-05-04 10:59:50:200 MDT] received value: No`

and then I changed the value in the sheet and the log read this:
`[15-05-04 10:57:49:470 MDT] received value: Yes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps, below is a code that works in my tests : (set up an installable trigger to make it work)

note : I added a couple of `Logger.log` here and there to check the variables and a `Browser` message to avoid sending mails while testing.

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 2");
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var col = cell.getA1Notation().replace(/[0-9]/g,'').toLowerCase();
  Logger.log('col = '+col);
  var cellValue = cell.getValue().toString().toLowerCase();
  Logger.log(cellValue);
  var recipients = "example@gmail.com";
  var message = '';
  Logger.log(cellValue=="yes" && col=='f');
  if(cellValue=="yes" && col=='f' ){ 
    message = sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
    var subject = 'A cell value '+ sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + ' has been received';
    var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: «' + row + '». New comment: «' + cellValue + '». For message: «' + message + '»';
//    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body)
    Browser.msgBox('mail sent');
  }
    Logger.log('message body: ' + body);
};
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much, Serge!  I clearly have a long way to go before I can code correctly.  =(

Answer (score 1):

To set up an event object use:

```
function sendNotification(e) {
  var received = e.value; //Gets the value of the edited cell
};
```

The code that is sending the email, is ***outside*** of the `if` body.  So the email is being sent no matter what.

Change to this:

```
if(received==="Yes"){ 
  message = sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()

  var subject = 'A cell value '+ sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + ' has been received';
  var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: «' + row + '». New comment: «' + cellvalue + '». For message: «' + message + '»';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
};
```

In this line of code:

```
if(received="Yes"){
```

You are using an assignment operator to check for equality.  Equality checks are done with double or triple equal signs.

Should be:

```
if(received==="Yes"){
```

Comment: Thanks!  I just added the triple equals sign, but unfortunately it is still sending an email any time a value is changed in a cell in column K instead of only when the value equals "Yes".

Comment: Thanks for that.  I changed it (I had to add a closing "}" to the code you had) to your suggestion.  However, it's still just sending messages no matter what the change is in the column.  I'm so stumped...

Comment: I would use an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) with your trigger to get the value of the edited cell.  I'm assuming that you are using a trigger.  E.g. `onChange()`

Comment: I'm using a basic trigger that Run's "Script Name" on Events "From Spreadsheet" "On Edit.

Unfortunately I don't know how to set up an event object with the trigger.  =(

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help with this.  So, I've updated the OP to reflect the code.  I put the event object above the sendnotification function, and I deleted the simple trigger that I had set up by going to "Current Project's Triggers".  

Unfortunately it is still just sending me a notification when any change is made to the sheet.  Should I build a template sheet that I can share here?

Comment: EDITED: I had to undo that simple trigger deletion because I'm pretty sure I needed that still.